# Can I tell if the HC-06 bluetooth is connected?

Tags: bluetooth

I seem to see that the HC-06 device behaves like a serial device with TX/RX.  I also understand that this needs to be "connected" to a blue tooth master to send/receive data.  Is there a way that I can tell from the HC-06 end whether or not it has a connection to its partner?

I plan to drive the HC-06 through an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, due to the limited HC-06 AT command set and lack of hardware support (This varies by revision or carrier board, your milage may vary). I got my limited information from http://mcuoneclipse.com/2013/06/19/using-the-hc-06-bluetooth-module/

The first is by connecting to the high end of the led on the carrier board (or to pin 24). If it is blinking/switching on and off, it is not paired. If it is a steady high/solid light, you are paired to the pc.

The second is to send an AT command. For example, if you send `AT` when not paired, you will get back `OK`. If you send `AT` while paired, you will not get a response. You can use this to know what is happening.

Comment: Thank you that was most helpful.  The second answer troubles me though ... when it is paired, won't sending `AT` cause the receiver to receive those two characters?

Comment: Yes. That's a trade off. The hc-06 firmware is very very dumb down simple. It's meant to be a transparent serial like. If you want something better go with a hc -05